# Yii2 override yii2-giiant

Tags: yii2, composer-php, yii2-giiant

I have made some changes in `yii2-giiant`. When I'm updating `yii2-giiant` these changes are of course lost. How to extend `yii2-giiant` so that my changes remain in case of an update also? (I mean the extension should be basically updated)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit composer-loaded vendor code the right way (in PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387387/how-to-edit-composer-loaded-vendor-code-the-right-way-in-php)

Comment: Probably you are right, however I think it's rather for professionals, because I don't really understand what's going on. So it means I have to add my version of `yii2-giiant` to my composer?

Comment: Yes, you can create your own fork of giiant and use it in your `composer.json` using `repositories` settings (there is plenty examples in google how to do this).