# How "replace" works with composer?

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I have a module Test/ABC and another module Test/ABCPRO (Which is extended version of Test/ABC).
Now if someone is trying to install Test/ABCPRO via composer- So at that time I need requirement such that if Test/ABC is already installed it should be replaced by Test/ABCPRO.
Can anyone please help me explain How it is possible via composer.json in magento 2?

I tried with replace function:

```
"replace":
{
    "test/abc":"self.version"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "replace" property work with composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882201/how-does-the-replace-property-work-with-composer)

Comment: As an addition to the other answer: `replace` won't remove packages you've already installed